# How to cover exactly 24 hours on DateTimeAxis? minimum/maximum not seeming to work

Tags: actionscript-3, datetime, apache-flex, charts

I want to show a full 24 hours along the datetimeaxis wherever the values fed into it happen to fall. I thought that setting the minimum and maximum of a datetime axis on the chart would have that effect.

so I have

```
private function loadDayComplete():void{ //called when data is reloaded. also includes reassigning the dataprovider of the chart.

 minChartDate = new Date;
 minChartDate.fullYear = currentDate.fullYear; 
 minChartDate.month = currentDate.month;
 minChartDate.date = currentDate.date;
 minChartDate.hours=0;
 minChartDate.minutes=0;
 minChartDate.seconds=0;
 minChartDate.milliseconds=0;
 maxChartDate = new Date; 
 maxChartDate.time = minChartDate.time + 1000*60*60*24;

 bgResults = _day.BGResults;

 bgTimeAxis.minimum = minChartDate;
 bgTimeAxis.maximum = minChartDate;

 glucoseSeries.dataProvider = bgResults;
}
```

currentDate is the date representing whatever date is selected in a DateField.

then I have

```
<mx:DateTimeAxis id="bgTimeAxis" dataUnits="hours" parseFunction="parseDateString" 
displayLocalTime="true" minimum="{minChartDate}" maximum="{maxChartDate}">
```

When I load up the function though it doesn't plot any points when the min and max are set. If I take out the minimum and maximum they show up fine!  I double checked in debug mode that the minChartDate and maxChartDate are what they should be.. but maybe I'm misunderstanding how minimum and maximum are supposed to function... I also tried widening the min/max to include several days and still no luck.

I also tried assigning the min/max when the chart data changes like so:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when set within the mxml itself it didn't keep the settings up to date, so I had to put

```
 bgTimeAxis.minimum = minChartDate;
 bgTimeAxis.maximum = maxChartDate;
```

in the populateData function and then it worked. I thought I had tried that already, but had a syntax error, and didn't realize that my solution was actually a solution.